# i have setting in app.setting i configure a service and i can read in my web project. i want to read in seprate library. asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i have a variable Appdiectory path in appsetting.json.

i read variable through use this code. Configure services method in startup.cs and Base controller code now i can read setting object in seprate class library.

Problem is i have section **appsetting** in appsetting.json.

now i want to read value of ImageAvatar and ActiveDirectory in seprate class library project.

```
"appSetting": {
    "ImageAvatar": "",
    "ActiveDirectory": ""
  }
```

Comment: What is the question? Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Update Done.@Nkosi

Comment: It is still not clear what the question is..

Comment: What do you mean by read value for `ImageAvatar` from class library? Will you reference this library in your web project? You could passing `IConfiguration` to class constructor.